# What is a C++ equivalent for "Environment.MachineName" under linux?

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming

It is defined in .NET Framework to get the NETBIOS name of the local computer. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename.aspx

If the solution is cross-platform it would be way better. :)

Comment: are you looking for hostname?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Yes, I think so. :)

Comment: @derekhh: there is no "standard C++" way to retrieve the hostname. However, you can use [unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/unistd.h.html) with C++.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: you mean, from POSIX...

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I meant "from inside/within/code written in", revised to read "with".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gethostname`. Here is the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738527%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Small note, he was looking for the [Linux docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/gethostname.html).